# Docker running but not accessible on localhost

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm very new to docker.
For my react app I wanted to create a docker container. So I followed the official tutorial on https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/.

I took over the Dockerfile, only changed the node version, and .dockerignore.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**.dockerignore**

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
```

Then, as described in the tutorial, I built the image with `docker build -t <your username>/node-web-app .` and run it with `docker run -p 49160:8080 -d <your username>/node-web-app`.

I know it ran successful because I checked the logs. Also from inside the container's bash I could do `curl -i localhost:8080` and got a valid html result.

Curling the server instance from my machine, doing `curl -i localhost:49160` gets me `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`.

I tried localhost, 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, my IPv4 address, also various ports. I don't understand this. I have no idea what could be the mistake as I did everything just like in the official documentation of nodejs.

Comment: Can you fix your `curl` command?  What flavor of Docker are you using (in particular, is it Docker Toolbox and/or Docker Machine)?

Comment: Checking the obvious: are you attempting (correctly) to connect to localhost on port 49160?

Comment: You should use `docker run -p 8080:8080 -d <your username>/node-web-app` and then try to access `localhost:8080` from your browser; otherwise, you are binding to port 49160 (`localhost:49160`)

Comment: Sorry I did not clarify in my question text. I was using the right port. Also when I do 8080:8080, it won't curl on 8080. do you have other suggestions?
@DavidMaze I am using Docker Desktop for Mac

Comment: Did you get a solution to your problem? Am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

`docker run -p 49160:8080` That mean you bind you 8080 port in docker container to 49160 port on real host machine. In your case, curl command from host machine must be `curl -i localhost:49160` not `8080`.

Comment: Sorry I did not clarify it in my question. I will update it. But of course I was using the right port, so unfortunately that was not the solution. but thanks anyway.